# How to reduce the spaces between div's in a form?

Tags: html, css

I designed a form like the below.

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Search</legend>
    <table>
        <tr>
           <td style="width:100px">
               Application
           </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</fieldset>
```

I am seeing the some space between fieldset and table .how to reduce the spaces between them.
like that my page having 4 div's in between div havig more space .please let me know i wrote the css as padding :0px like that but not reducign the space between the div's.

Please let me know.

Comment: please provide a http://jsfiddle.net/ oh and what you discribe sounds like you want to try negativ values something like `margin:-10px;`

Comment: _How to reduce the spaces between div's,_! Where are `divs`?

Comment: please provide jsfiddle also try css reset: meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/‎

Comment: The code sample provided doesn't match the question *at all*.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this down in jsfiddle and played around.

This is your example:

http://jsfiddle.net/c4d68/1/

And watching what CSS the element has, i wrote a new one without those spaces.

Is maybe this what u are searching for?

http://jsfiddle.net/gqzr6/1/

```
Regards
```

I added some borders to the table, to make the examples more clear and the difference of space.